# Creating new array object from existing API object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, reduce

I am trying to filter out the "Country" key values in an array.
Below is the JSON structure.

```
let apidata = [
    {
        "Brand":"Puma",
        "id": "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd",
        "Country": [
            {
                "City": "Mumbai",
                "Location": "Andheri",
            },{
                "City": "Bangalore",
                "Location": "MG Road",
            },
        ],
        "Shipping": [
            {
                "pincode":"112144",
                "shipping":"yes",
            },{
                "pincode":"111451",
                "shipping":"No",
            },
        ]
    },{
        "Brand":"adidas",
        "id": "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321xv",
        "Country": [
            {
                "City": "Chennai",
                "Location": "Marina",
            },{
                "City": "Gurgaon",
                "Location": "Huda City",
            },
        ],
        "Shipping": [
            {
                "pincode":"114144",
                "shipping":"yes",
            },{
                "pincode":"111414",
                "shipping":"No",
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

The expected output should be:

```
b = [
        {
            "City": "Mumbai",
            "Location": "Andheri",
            "uid": 0
        },
        {
            "City": "Bangalore",
            "Location": "MG Road",
            "uid": 1
        },
        {
            "City": "Chennai",
            "Location": "Marina",
            "uid": 0
        },
        {
            "City": "Gurgaon",
            "Location": "Huda City",
            "uid": 1
        }
    ]
```

**Below is the code which I was trying to implement**

```
let b = [];
apidata.map((ele) => {
    return Object.keys(ele).filter(key => key === "Country").reduce((obj, ele1, index) => {
      // debugger;
        if(b.length == 0)
            b = ele[ele1].map((i,index)=>({...i,"uid":index}));
        else
             b = [...b, ...ele[ele1].map((i,index)=>({...i,"uid":index}))]  ;
        
        return b
        
    },{})
})
```

I used filter concept to filter out the keys and combined with reduce to create a new object. But I am not able to get the output required.

Can someone pls help me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Don't use `filter`. Everything you want is just in the `Country` property, so just use `ele.Country`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to filter the keys when you only want one property. Just access that property directly.

Use `flatMap()` to merge the results of mapping each `Country` property into a single array.

```js
let apidata = [{
  "Brand": "Puma",
  "id": "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321bd",
  "Country": [{
    "City": "Mumbai",
    "Location": "Andheri",
  }, {
    "City": "Bangalore",
    "Location": "MG Road",
  }, ],
  "Shipping": [{
    "pincode": "112144",
    "shipping": "yes",
  }, {
    "pincode": "111451",
    "shipping": "No",
  }, ]
}, {
  "Brand": "adidas",
  "id": "c5d58bef-f1c2-4b7c-a6d7-f64df12321xv",
  "Country": [{
    "City": "Chennai",
    "Location": "Marina",
  }, {
    "City": "Gurgaon",
    "Location": "Huda City",
  }, ],
  "Shipping": [{
    "pincode": "114144",
    "shipping": "yes",
  }, {
    "pincode": "111414",
    "shipping": "No",
  }, ]
}, ];

let result = apidata.flatMap(({Country}) => Country.map((city, i) => ({...city, uid: i})));
console.log(result);
```